# not able to get data and display from parse server

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com to store my data and I want to retrive a certain object and I don't get any error or exception , just an empty activity, I tried to `extends` `ListActivity` with `setListAdapter()` instead of `AppCompatActivity`,`Activity` but I get different error

ProblemList.java

```
public class ProblemList extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<Problems> problemsList = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_problem_list);
    new DataFetch().execute();
}
private class DataFetch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProblemList.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Getting data from Parse.com servers");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        problemsList=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Problem");
            ob=query.find();
            for (ParseObject problem : ob)
            {
                Problems p=new Problems();
                p.setReportDate(problem.getCreatedAt().toString());
                p.setReportUser((String) problem.get("Username"));
                p.setReportInfo((String) problem.get("problem"));
                problemsList.add(p);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(ProblemList.this, problemsList);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

listviewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Problems> problemlist = null;
private ArrayList<Problems> arraylist;
public ListViewAdapter(Context context,List<Problems> problemlist) {
    this.context=context;
    this.problemlist=problemlist;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist=new ArrayList<Problems>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(problemlist);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return problemlist.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return problemlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows, parent);
        holder.mDate= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reportDate);
        holder.mProblem= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reportMsg);
        holder.mUsername=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reportedUser);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
       holder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.mDate.setText(problemlist.get(position).getReportDate());
    holder.mProblem.setText(problemlist.get(position).getReportInfo());
    holder.mUsername.setText(problemlist.get(position).getReportUser());
    return view;
}
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView mDate;
    TextView mUsername;
    TextView mProblem;
}
}
```

Problem.java (setters and getters)

```
public class Problems {
String reportUser;
String reportDate;
String reportInfo;
public String getReportUser() {
    return reportUser;
}
public void setReportUser(String reportUser) {
    this.reportUser = reportUser;
}

public String getReportDate() {
    return reportDate;
}
public void setReportDate(String reportDate) {
    this.reportDate = reportDate;
}

public String getReportInfo() {
    return reportInfo;
}

public void setReportInfo(String reportInfo) {
    this.reportInfo = reportInfo;
}
}
```

xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I followed this tutorial [here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/) , thanks for your time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I suggest to use custom which extend ParseObject. So ypur problem should extend ParseObject.
Then Parse sdk provide two method for each request. One is asynk and other one is synk. So, you shouldn' t use AsynkTask. I put below an example took from api reference:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

method done is a callback and all this code is runnin on separate thread.

Parse offers to you simple adapter (yes you can extend it) for show data on listview.
Keep in mind that Parse will close next years.

Comment: I tried more simple code in site's reference and it worked , about parse going out of services I don't have problem with that since I'm working on my college project. thanks